# Building a python egg, first letter is incorrectly removed from root file/folder name

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, setuptools, egg

I'm trying to build an egg for my python project using `setuptools`, however, whenever I build an egg all of the contents are built with the first letter if each file/folder removed.

For example, my parent folder is called `dp` which gets renamed to `p`. I.e. when I unzip the egg file, I see a parent folder named `p` and another folder named `GG-INFO` (these should be named `dp` and `EGG-INFO` respectively). All of the other folders inside folder `p` are named correctly.

This is an issue because I reference functions in modules within that folder - e.g. `from dp.module import function` which doesn't work because it complains about not finding the folder `dp` (which is true since for some reason it's been renamed `p`).

My `setup.py` file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name="dp",
    version="1.0",
    author="XXXX",
    author_email="XXXX",
    description="Data pipeline for XXX algorithm.",
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="XXXX",
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={'': ['*.sql', '*.json', '*.txt']},
    include_package_data=True,
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3"
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=['argparse', 'boto3', 'datetime', 'mmlspark', 'pandas', 'pyspark', 'pypandoc', 'scikit-learn',
                      'numpy', 'googleads', 'mlflow']
)
```

I've tried renaming the parent directory and the same thing happens. I'm running this via PyCharm (updated to the latest version) on Mac OS Mojave.

Would appreciate any ideas on how to fix this.

[image: File Structure]

[image: Renamed folders]

**Update:**
I used a different method to generate the egg which unblocked me, but the issue still remains with the initial method.

**Steps to reproduce**

- Create a new project in Pycharm
- Add a setup.py file to root, see above.
- Tools -> Run setup.py task -> bdist.egg
- Generates an egg. Rename the extension to `file_name.zip`, unzip the file, check the contents of the folder.
- I found that the first letter of the folder names was always missing (i changed the names of the folder and it consistently removed the first letter).

**Workaround**

- Instead of building an egg via Pycharm, i used the command `python setup.py bdist_egg` in the terminal which created an egg without any issues.
- I think this confirms it is a Pycharm bug(?). A colleague managed to intermittently reproduce this bug using Pycharm.

Comment: Can you describe the exact steps to reproduce this?

Comment: How do you use setuptools? E.g. which command do you run to build an egg?

Comment: The issue is not reproducible using the code you provided. Clearly, your issue lies somewhere else. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are building an *egg* of all things in 2020? Wheels are a standard these days.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's removing the first letter? E.g. if you use the name `elephant` instead of `dp`, do you end up with `lephant` or still `p`?

Comment: @ArthurTacca - yes, i've tried different names and it always removes the first letter of the string. (`elephant` does become `lephant`).

Comment: @Tim496 Can you describe the exact steps to reproduce this?

Answer (score 2):

Give the wheel a try.

```
pip install wheel setuptools pip -U
pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir=build .
```